# what changes or configuration required to setup Dynamic Data website in SDL Tridion

Tags: dd4t

Anyone can guide/help me by providing document on how to get Dynamic data behaviour from SDL Tridion. 
What changes do I need to make in Tridion Configuration to make a publication workable with DD4T way?

Answer (score 4):

That's a pretty broad question, I recommend reading SDL's own **Content Delivery** documentation which can be found here:

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-91BEBD21-B99B-4E95-8F83-01B3909D4751

(you need your log in to access)

Once you understand how this works, I then go and read about setting up a DD4T application here:

https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/wiki/TableOfContents?tm=6

Comment: Also, check out this awesome tutorial from Rob: http://www.building-blocks.com/thinking/getting-started-with-dd4t-1-31-asp-net-mvc4-and-sdl-tridion-2013/